# Prototyping-orientated features in Python?

Tags: php, python, prototype-oriented

I have written a PHP application and have a problem that I cannot solve in a good way in PHP. So I am thinking over porting it to Ruby or Python--two languages I never used before. As far as I've seen this problem could be solved in Ruby and my question is now if I can solve it in Python, too:

The core of the application has a class A that I want to extend. There is one extension E1 that extends A by a method doFoo and one extension E2 that extends A by a method doBar. Now I want to use both extensions without having to change the code of A, E1 or E2. In PHP this could be archived by writing a third extension E3, that provides a class B that extends A and mixes in E1 and E2 with traits or by some other dirty tricks. But I want to be able to have the core, to have these two extensions and to have the info in the config: "use extensions E1 and E2" without the necessity of any more classes that puts everything together (and without using __call()).

Is that possible in Python in any way? I don't really need prototypes that could be changed during runtime. Every instance of A should have doFoo and doBar.

**EDIT:** The whole thing should work without extensions, with only E1 (without E2), with only E2 (without E1) and with both extensions.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  Why can't you use simple inheritance?

Comment: Ah, I forgot this: E1 should also be usable without E2 and E2 should also be usable without E2. Thank you.

Comment: @stofl: you mean "E1", right?

Comment: ... yes ... sorry. I edited the question above.

Comment: It sounds like you might want [duck punching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_punching). Although my guess is that what you want here is not actually the best way to accomplish whatever it is you want.

Comment: This applies to both the current answers, so I'm putting it here:  Try and rethink your problem, as @WayneWerner is suggesting.  We just underwent a multi-month refactoring effort to remove code that uses `type` to dynamically create classes that, months after being written, no one understood.  They just kept growing in complexity.

Comment: Yes I know the dark side... Thank you all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mailson suggested, multiple inheritance is the way to go. A simple

```
class E(A, E1, E2):
    ...
```

Should do what you need.

EDIT:
To do it dynamically you can use type:

```
E = type("E", (A, E1, E2), {})
```

EDIT2: Dougal beat me to it :D

Comment: This would mean to (hard)code a custom class E, right? I don't want to code "enable E1 and E2"--I want to configure it (without something like an auto generation of the code of class E).

Answer (score 1):

You can do the suggested multiple inheritance without hardcoding like this:

```
mixins = (E1, E2)
E = type('E', (A,) + mixins, {})
```

which is like doing

```
class E(A, E1, E2):
    pass
```

but allows you to specify the mixins dynamically.